# How to add a child window created by GLFW to C# panel?

Tags: c#, glfw

I've got the handle of the parent window created by C#, and here is the code:

```
window->win32.dwStyle = WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN LWS_CHILDWINDOW| WS_VISIBLE;
window->win32.dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
CreateWindowExW(window->win32.dwExStyle,
                _GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME,
                wideTitle,
                window->win32.dwStyle,
                xpos, ypos,
                fullWidth, fullHeight,
                window->win32.parentHandle, // will modified
                NULL, // No window menu
                GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                window); // Pass object to WM_CREATE
```

but it won't work and doesn't show the window.I guess it might be the dwStyle and the dwExStyle that work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call ShowWindow for showing. You just create, but you don't show

```
HWND hwnd=CreateWindowExW(window->win32.dwExStyle,
                _GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME,
                wideTitle,
                window->win32.dwStyle,
                xpos, ypos,
                fullWidth, fullHeight,
                window->win32.parentHandle, // will modified
                NULL, // No window menu
                GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                NULL); // //here is NULL
ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);//nCmdShow is int
UpdateWindow(hwnd);//For sure you update window.
```